# Unexpected Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino, port

I'm building a windows forms program on Visual Studio 2013 (C#) which reads data from Serial Port (in my case - Arduino) and use it to change a picture. The Arduino returns an 8-bit string of 0's and 1's, which indicates what picture to change. For example - if the string is `10001001` the program should change the 1'st, 5'th and 8'th picture. The program is able to get the correct string from the Serial Port (via Serial Communication), but when I added a method that makes the picture to change, it **sometimes** gives me this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

and point that line on `Program.cs`:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

(My form name is "form1.cs" and the namespace is serial_read)

Here's what the program looks like:
[image]

And here's my form1.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace Serial_receive
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort(); //Defines Serial Port

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;

        foreach (string port in SerialPort.GetPortNames()) {comboBox1.Items.Add(port);} //Gives a list of the available ports

        serialPort1.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;
    }

   private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
   {
       string line = serialPort1.ReadLine(); //The serial string
       this.BeginInvoke(new LineReceivedEvent(LineReceived), line);

   }
   private delegate void LineReceivedEvent(string line);

   //Change image to a different image
   private void changeColor(PictureBox ob, string line, int l) //ob = PictureBox, line = the serial string, l = number of PictureBox
   {
       if (int.Parse(line.Substring(l, 1)) == 1)
           ob.Image = Serial_receive.Properties.Resources.red;
   }

   private void LineReceived(string line)
   {
       label1.Text = line;

       changeColor(l1, line, 0); //Picture 1
       changeColor(l2, line, 1); //Picture 2
       changeColor(l3, line, 2); //Picture 3
       changeColor(l4, line, 3); //Picture 4
       changeColor(l5, line, 4); //Picture 5
       changeColor(l6, line, 5); //Picture 6
       changeColor(l7, line, 6); //Picture 7
       changeColor(l8, line, 7); //Picture 8

   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Start Button
   {
       serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text.ToString();

       if (comboBox1.Text.ToString() == "Select Port... (Default: COM4)" || comboBox1.Text.ToString() == "")
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM4";
       serialPort1.Open();
       button1.Enabled = false;
   }
}
```

}

Any ideas why I get this error? I'm kinda new to C# and don't really know what's the problem..

Comment: We need to know that exception's InnerException to know what could have gone wrong.  You debug it with Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.  The debugger now stops when the exception is thrown.

Comment: OK, did it. Here's the new error: 

`A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: index and length must refer to a location within the string.` 

And here's anoteher error (that points on the line `Application.Run(new Form1());` on Program.cs:
`A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

Comment: Well, you are doing something wrong with a string.  Probably that line.Substring() call, it blindly assumes that the string has at least two characters.  Kaboom if it doesn't.  Use that Debug + Exceptions dialog.